# Dag python automatisation

Tags: python-3.x, variables, airflow, extract

```
'''
 task : extraction des données journalières '''

import os
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import logging
import pendulum
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import models
from airflow.models import Variable 
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import Variable
import subprocess

Variable.set('startfrom', '0')
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 12, 11),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'run_script',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Run a Python script every day at 6:00 AM',
    schedule_interval='0 6 * * *',
)
# ...

def run_my_script():
   
    start_from = Variable.get('startfrom', default_var='0')
    script_path = "billetiques/script_1.py"
    
   
    result = subprocess.run(["python", script_path, "--start-from", start_from], capture_output=True, text=True)
    
   
    new_start_from = result.stdout.strip()  # Récupérer la sortie du script
    # Mise à jour de la variable start_from dans Airflow
    Variable.set('startfrom', new_start_from)



run_script_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_script',
    python_callable=run_my_script,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Hello, i create a dag that executes every morning at 6 :00 am to do an extraction from a database.

My problem is that i don't know how to change some variable in my dag to get only the data for a day not all the data of the days .

exemple :

On 20/12/2022 : i launch my script and it returns 50000 rows.

On 21/12/2022 : i launched my script and it returns 6200 rows.

...

i would like that my dag take in consideration the date  and other variables (change the date (variable) ) every time he runs. If someone have a solution please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the below line which is outside the DAG context

```
Variable.set('startfrom', '0')
```

The above code has two downside

- It will always make a call to metadata while parsing DAG file
- And, It will always update startfrom to 0

And if your variable is not string type then need to typecast it once you fetch it because you will always get string type with

```
Variable.get('startfrom', default_var='0')
```

here is a smaller version of your DAG

```
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.models import Variable

dag = DAG(
    'run_script',
    start_date=datetime(2023, 12, 11),
    schedule_interval='0 6 * * *',
)


def run_my_script():
    start_from = Variable.get('startfrom', default_var='0')
    print("start from = ", start_from)
    new_start_from = int(start_from) + 1
    Variable.set('startfrom', new_start_from)


run_script_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_script',
    python_callable=run_my_script,
    dag=dag,
)
```

- For the 1st run print start from =  0
- For the 2nd run print start from =  1